# Why is .js code working by console but not in form of a plug in?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, google-docs

I am trying to remove an element
For this purpose I am trying to make small plug in in .js
I have tailored this to this one specific google form I want to use it at, and for some reason I am haveing more issues in docs.google.com than I have in other websites

```js
// content.js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxxxx");
element[0].remove();
```

*"xxxxx" is the class of the block that holds the email display, I've changed it here, idk if one could pull the emails with it*

When I paste the code in the console manually it works as I want it ,
but if I run it by plug in it gives me an error code:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read Properties of undefined (reading 'remove')"

Edit:
Upon request the manifest.json and the timer, I bet theres also a better way to do it

```json
//manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Auto Delete xxxxxx Elements",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A Chrome extension to automatically delete elements containing the class 'xxxxxx' on doc.google.com.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://docs.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      chrome.tabs.query({ url: "*://docs.google.com/*" }, tabs => {
        tabs.forEach(tab => {
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            files: ['content.js']
          });
        });
      });
    }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
  });
```

Comment: @Yogi I have edited the post, and yes I indeed meant a chrome/ium extension

Answer (score 1):

Looks like element[0] is undefined when you're trying to access it's remove() method.
The plugin might be executing before the element is loaded onto the page.

You could change the plugin code to wait for the page to load before calling the remove function that removes the element via DOMContentLoaded event or window.onload event.

Something like the below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxxxx");
    if (element.length > 0) {
        element[0].remove(); 
    } else {
        console.error("Element with class 'xxxxxx' not found.");
    }
});
```

So here it waits for the DOMContentLoaded event before calling remove().
It also checks if the element with class "xxxxxx" exists before trying to remove it.

Edit: try this for background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
        if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.startsWith('https://docs.google.com/')) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tabId },
                files: ['content.js']
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hm now its like half flipped
I dont read any errors anymore from the plug in
Neither in the source tab or from console.error.
But when I paste this into the console it returns "Undefined". I dont know if I am looking in the wrong place for the error code. Just in case, yes I rememberd to replace it with the right class again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really that skilled, but you may be getting that error because of all the nesting, try this.

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("xxxxxx");
element[0].innerHTML = "";
element[0].remove();
```

Also, make sure the website is fully loaded before your plugin executes the code.

Comment: Sadly when I put this into the console I get the error codes "This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment." and "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.". I havent tried to implement it in the plug in yet, and replaced with the right class